# Problem when enabling production mode on magento 2

Tags: magento2

[image]I've installed an extension via ssh on magento 2, compiled and everithing is ok.
The problem is that when enabling production mode i have the error in the image.
Any thoughs? Let me know if you need more information, thank you (magento 2.2.4)

Comment: try to di compile

Comment: please check other logs, is it permissions or magento bug, 2.2.4???? latest version is 2.3.3, why you still work with 2.2???

Answer (score 2):

Change the mode and skip the compilation:

```
php magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation
```

And once the mode is switched you can deploy static content with GB locale.

```
php magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB
```

Comment: i've tried this method but the backend doesen't show properly. The problem is also that in developer mode i can access the backend, but the site is not visible in either mode. I have an internal server error. Could be the new extension?

Answer (score 0):

So in the end i had to uninstall the extension since the frontend of the store was completely blocked.
I've tried to install the same extension on a fresh local magento install but i had errors too. Since the extension have no official support i think that i'll try another plugin.
Thanks for the reply all!

Answer (score -1):

For now you can use below command to change production mode. It will not throw any error.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s
```

Comment: in developer mode i can access the backend but if i go into developer mode with this method i cannot access the backend anymore. The site is not showing in all the modes. Maybe the new extension is creating problems? the extenion is this: https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-search.html/

Comment: why he needs to hide output???

Comment: @MagenX I said `For now you can use` in the starting of the answer. I'm not saying it is good to hide output. It's temporary solution.